# map marker info ins not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i just stuck in a problem with google-map multi marker script, i have multiple markers and when i clink on the external link for location the map zoomed in specific google lat, lon .

but if you can see i have info box on every marker.if i click on the map marker it open the info box. but when i click on external zoom link it didn't  display the info box of marker.

can anyone help me in this matter. please check the example in below link

http://saudisoftechportal.us/map.html

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when you click the external link, the resetMap method pans to the required LatLng and zooms to the given zoomlevel, but does not open the infowindow at the marker. Maybe you should use a markers array too according to the locations.
Here is a sample for your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    .maker{ margin:auto;}
    .maker li{ list-style:none; float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:8px;}
    .maker li img{ width:34px; height:34px; display:block; float:left;}
    .maker li span{ display: block; float: left; line-height: 27px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="span4">
        <ul id="markerul" class="maker">
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var infowindow;
        var marker;
        var markers = [];
        var locations = [
              ['<strong>Head Office Khobar</strong>', 26.3411159,50.1936446,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',0],
              ['<strong>Dammam Office</strong>', 26.409727,50.1314224,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',1],
              ['<strong>Khafji Office</strong>', 28.4155603,48.509478,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',2],
              ['<strong>Riyadh Office</strong>', 24.6717577,46.7262669,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',3],
              ['<strong>Jeddah Office</strong>', 21.5228383,39.1793113,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',4],
              ['<strong>Warehouse</strong>', 26.4152548,50.1606446,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',5],
              ['<strong>Workshop</strong>', 26.4146399,50.156845,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',6],
              ['<strong>PMT Office</strong>', 14.576208,120.997944,'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/map-marker-icons-49653.png',7]
        ];
        function initMap(){
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 5,
              scrollwheel: false,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.884248, 45.078492),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: locations[i][3]
                });
                markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i));
            }

            listFill();
        }
        function resetMap(elem, zoom) {
            var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[elem][1], locations[elem][2]);
            infowindow.setContent(locations[elem][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, markers[elem]);
            map.setZoom(zoom);
            map.panTo(newPos);
        };
        function listFill(){
            $('#markerul ul').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                var liItem = '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="resetMap(' + i + ',15);"><img src="' + locations[i][3] + '" alt="' +  locations[i][0] + '"/><span>' + locations[i][0] + '</span></a></li>';
                $('#markerul').append(liItem);
            };
        };
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I hope it helps!